# Creating a dask dataframe from a list of HDF5 files

Tags: python, pandas, dask

What is the correct way to go about creating a dask.dataframe from a list of HDF5 files? I basically want to do this but with a dataframe

```
dsets = [h5py.File(fn)['/data'] for fn in sorted(glob('myfiles.*.hdf5')]
arrays = [da.from_array(dset, chunks=(1000, 1000)) for dset in dsets]
x = da.stack(arrays, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Briefly if your individual files can be read with `pd.read_hdf` then you can do this with `dd.read_hdf` and `dd.concat`.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
dfs = [dd.read_hdf(fn, '/data') for fn in sorted(glob('myfiles.*.hdf5')]
df = dd.concat(dfs)
```

But it would be useful (and easy) to support this idiom within `dd.read_hdf` directly.  I've created [an issue](https://github.com/blaze/dask/issues/624) for this and will try to get to it in the next couple of days.